# JQuery click event target / button opens two dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I'm using asp.net webGrid in which i have two buttons which both open same dialog (with different content) and a dialog which is supposed to open only when clicked on the current row (not from button clicks). I have this if else which checks if the clicked element is a button or not.

The problem is that this works fine the first time after loading the page. If i click only the buttons it opens the correct dialog. But after first time clicking a row, button clicks now open both dialogs at once.

Here's the code,

```
$('#grid').click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).is(':button'))
    {
        $('.edit-db').live('click', function () {
            $.getJSON('/Methods/dbQuery/' + $(this).attr('id'), function (data) {
                var lista = data;
                $('#edit-id').val(lista.id);
                $('#edit-nimi').val(lista.nimi);
                $('#edit-ip').val(lista.ip);
            });
            $('#action-type').val('edit');
            tyyppi = 'edit';
            $("#edit").show();
            $("#delete").hide();
            $('#dialog-edit').dialog('open');
        });

        $('.delete-row').live('click', function () {
            $.getJSON('/Methods/dbQuery/' + $(this).attr('id'), function (data) {
                var lista = data;
                $('#edit-id').val(lista.id);
            });
            $('#action-type').val('delete');
            $("#edit").hide();
            $("#delete").show();
            $('#dialog-edit').dialog('open');
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('tbody tr').live('hover', function () {
            id = $(this).find('td:first').text();
            $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
        }).live('click', function () {
            $("#devInfo").load("deviceInfo.cshtml/" + id).dialog('open');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the click handler around the `live()` method calls. Because you have one, the `live()` is being repeatedly set on those elements after each click.

The `is(':button')` check is redundant as a `tr` element can never be a button anyway.

Also, `live()` has been deprecated. If you are using jQuery 1.7+ you should use `on()`, otherwise you should use `delegate()`.

Try this:

```
$('#grid').delegate('.edit-db', 'click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.getJSON('/Methods/dbQuery/' + $(this).attr('id'), function (data) {
        var lista = data;
        $('#edit-id').val(lista.id);
        $('#edit-nimi').val(lista.nimi);
        $('#edit-ip').val(lista.ip);
    });
    $('#action-type').val('edit');
    tyyppi = 'edit';
    $("#edit").show();
    $("#delete").hide();
    $('#dialog-edit').dialog('open');
});
.delegate('.delete-row', 'click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $.getJSON('/Methods/dbQuery/' + $(this).attr('id'), function (data) {
        var lista = data;
        $('#edit-id').val(lista.id);
    });
    $('#action-type').val('delete');
    $("#edit").hide();
    $("#delete").show();
    $('#dialog-edit').dialog('open');
});
.delegate('tbody tr', 'hover', function () {
    id = $(this).find('td:first').text();
    $(this).toggleClass('clickable');
})
.delegate('tbody tr', 'click', function () {
    $("#devInfo").load("deviceInfo.cshtml/" + id).dialog('open');
});
```

Comment: With this buttons still open both dialogs(#devInfo and #dialog-edit) at the same time. When buttons are only supposed to open #dialog-edit and the row clicks #devInfo.

Comment: In that case you need to stop propagation of the buttons by adding `event.stopPropagation()` to the button handlers - I've updated my answer.